# Have any HCSSs (supermassive black holes with a tight bunch of gravitationally bound stars) ever been detected?

Tags: black-hole, supermassive-black-hole

[This article](https://www.sciencealert.com/there-could-be-runaway-missing-link-black-holes-zooming-around-the-universe) from sciencealert states:

> Astronomers think these two galactic cores could merge into one larger
> black hole, sending huge gravitational waves rippling out across
> spacetime. But if there's any asymmetry in the galactic merger, the
> newly forged black hole could be punted clean out of the galaxy and
> sent zooming across the Universe by gravitational wave recoil, taking
> a swarm of stars with it. Such runaway objects, theorised in the late
> noughties, are called hypercompact stellar systems (HCSSs) - a
> supermassive black hole with a tight bunch of gravitationally bound
> stars, careening away into the cosmos.

This article was written in 2020; now is the end of 2021.
Have any HCSSs (supermassive black holes with a tight bunch of gravitationally bound stars) been detected since then?

What projects are currently actively searching for HCSSs?

Comment: Did you read here? There has not yet been a confident identification of such a system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercompact_stellar_system#Search

Comment: @Daddy Kropotkin The referred by me article was of 2020. Now is the end of 2021... Has anything changed by now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The referred by me article was of 2020. Now is the end of 2021... Were any HCSSs - (supermassive black holes with a tight bunch of gravitationally bound stars) have been detected since then by now?

No, not yet.

> What projects are currently actively searching for HCSSs?

This recent study, [A Search for Wandering Black Holes in the Milky Way with Gaia and DECaLS](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021ApJ...917...17G/abstract), for such systems near the Milky Way used data from Gaia and DECaLs. They expected to see "~100 wandering intermediate-mass black holes if every infalling satellite hosts a black hole," but no such black holes were found in their search.

For future outlook, this recent study, [Hypercompact stellar clusters: morphological renditions and spectrophotometric models](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/495/2/1771/5831081), explores prospects for observing these systems with "Pan-STARRS and in forthcoming Euclid images."